# How to trace payment gateway has timeout while request for payments

Tags: timeout, payment-gateway

I am using Ezidebit payment gateway but some times it did not respond me and throw 503 timeout error. For handling this situation in my site I need to perform some action but how can I trace this. 
Please help!

Comment: Is it a hosted payment page or a curl connection? how about showing your code?

Comment: @user3086805: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks for comment, I am requesting by SOAP. Here is my script

Comment: $mycustomerfunction = "Addpayment";
 $mycustomerrequest = array (
 'DigitalKey' => $digital_key,                          
 'EziDebitCustomerID' => $pgtoken,                       
 'YourSystemReference' => '',
 'DebitDate' => $due_date,
 'PaymentAmountInCents' => $amount, 
 'PaymentReference' => $add, 
 'Username' => $user_name 
 );
 ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',0);
 ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',0);
 $client = new SoapClient($url, array("trace" => 1, "exception" => 0));
 $result = $client->{$mycustomerfunction}($mycustomerrequest);
 $response = $result->AddPaymentResult;